# SwiftでTabBArControllerのアイコンをオリジナルのものにしたい

Tags: swift, xcode

TabBarControllerのアイコンをオリジナルのものにしたいのですが、いろいろなサイトを見てもstoryboardを使ったものやObject-Cを使ったものしか見つけられません。

プログラムを書いてアイコンをオリジナルのものにするにはどのようなプログラムを書いたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

> いろいろなサイトを見てもstoryboardを使ったものやObject-Cを使ったものしか見つけられません。

iOSアプリ開発に関する情報は、あたりまえのことですが、Objective-Cをもとに書かれたものが大多数であり、それらを「言語が異なる」という理由だけで、調査の対象から外すというのは、妥当な行為とはいえません。Objective-Cをいまから学習しろとはいいません。おおくの情報では、言語に関係なく、作業、処理のおおまかな流れを説明している箇所があるはずで、その箇所だけ読んでも、じゅうぶん参考になるのではありませんか？

閑話休題。

Tab Barに表示される、Tab Bar Item（アイコン画像＋タイトル文字列）は、View Controllerに属しています。なので、アイコンの変更は、View Controllerに対してメソッドを送る、あるいはView Controllerのプロパティを変更するという処理になります。
対象のView Controllerのインスタンス名を`hogeViewController`とすると、

```
hogeViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "hoge", image: UIImage(named: "hoge.png", tag: 0)
```

これでTab Bar Itemのタイトルが「hoge」、アイコンが「hoge.png」に変わります。